# Conditionals weirdness

Tags: sql

I am running a query that effectively looks like

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN name LIKE '%ad%' AND x > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_x,
       SUM(CASE WHEN name LIKE '%ad%' AND y > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_y,
       SUM(CASE WHEN name LIKE '%ad%' AND z > 0  AND Z <= 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_z,
       SUM(CASE WHEN name LIKE '%ad%' AND x > 0 OR y > 0 OR z > 0  AND Z <= 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as distinct_streams
FROM table
```

The purpose of the query is to find the number of ad playbacks that meet different error conditions. I also want to find the distinct number of erroneous streams as some of the conditions could happen during the same stream. 
The problem is that the above query returns a larger number of distinct_streams then the 3 above combined. Do you see anything in that could be causing this?

Comment: which DBMS? What's the source data? What's the expected output? What does it output now? We've only got one piece of the puzzle here. Probably this is about operator precedence but it's hard to give an exact solution without further information. The requirements are too vague (we don't know how you define "erroneous", just as one example) and there's no sample data to work with. Don't forget we can only use what's in front of us. We can't access your screen, your disk, or your mind.

Comment: `and` binds stronger than `or`. Use parentheses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL all `AND` are evaluated before all `OR`.

So a criteria like:

```
name LIKE '%ad%' AND x > 0 OR y > 0 OR z > 0 AND z <= 100
```

Is actually evaluated as:

```
(name LIKE '%ad%' AND x > 0) OR y > 0 OR (z > 0 AND z <= 100)
```

While you probably expected:

```
name LIKE '%ad%' AND (x > 0 OR y > 0 OR (z > 0 AND z <= 100))
```

So try this:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN x > 0 THEN 1 END) AS num_x,
COUNT(CASE WHEN y > 0 THEN 1 END) AS num_y,
COUNT(CASE WHEN z > 0  AND z <= 100 THEN 1 END) AS num_z,
COUNT(CASE WHEN x > 0 OR y > 0 OR (z > 0 AND z <= 100) THEN 1 END) AS distinct_streams
FROM "table" AS t
WHERE name LIKE '%ad%';
```

Basically, when using both `AND` and `OR` it's often safer to include parentheses. Just to avoid misunderstandings with the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the fact that the logical `and` has a higher precedence than the logical `or`. Surround the `or` sequence with parenthesis and you should be OK:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN (name LIKE "%ad% AND (x > 0 OR y > 0 OR z > 0 AND Z <= 100) 
         THEN 1 
         ELSE 0
    END) as distinct_streams
```